# C++ undeclared identifier - object from .net dll class

Tags: c++, vb.net, com, dll, object-initializers

I have a vb.net dll which I imported in an unmanaged c++ project.

I successfully created an object of the class object using:

```
CComPtr< IWSconnection > pIWSconnection; 
pIWSconnection.CoCreateInstance( __uuidof(IWSconnection ) );
```

Then, when I tried to call a method from the dll: 
    pIWSconnection.connect(...);
I am getting an error: pIWSconnection undeclared identifier.

Why would the object work with 'CoCreateInstance', and not with 'connect'?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pIWSconnection variable is probably out of the scope when you call connect.
You need to use -> to call methods of the interface wrapped by CComPtr, by the way, . is for members of the CComPtr class.